# howto set the size of a Canvas, which doesn't have a layout

Tags: java, swt

I am subclassing the Canvas in SWT, and calling pack() inside of the constructor,
the Canvas' size is computed as 64x64.

There is no Style or layout inside of my class.

- How is the size computed at this here?
- How can I change the size of my class?  `this.setSize()` doesn't work.

```
    public MyClass(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, SWT.NONE);
        this.setBackground(getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW));

        this.computeSize(1000, 1000, true);
        this.pack();

        Point s = this.getSize();
        System.out.println(s.x); //prints 64
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give yourself the size : it is given by the layout of the component using your MyClass.

So your canvas should be ready to handle any size.

Answer (score 3):

If you are subclassing Canvas then you can also override the computeSize method to force specific element sizes.  This can be useful to make other elements flow around a fixed size component without having to use the layout hints, or if you want to make the canvas size set based on say an image that it's rendering.

This might be something like this in your MyCanvas class:

```
public Point computeSize (int widthHint, int heightHint, boolean changed) {
  Point initialSize = super.computeSize (widthHint, heightHint, changed);
  initialSize.x = 1000;
  initialSize.y = 1000;
  return initialSize;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `computeSize` is never called for my case. If it matters - I inserted my Canvas Instance into a Shell controlled by a FormLayout

Comment: There are two computeSize methods, one with the boolean and one without, but playing with my test app I always get the Composite's version, which is with the boolean.  I see computeSize called on:  shell.open(), shell.layout(), and shell.pack().  You shouldn't need any of the size methods like you've got in your MyCanvas constructor above (computeSize, pack, etc.).  Instead, try calling it on the shell (either layout or pack).

Comment: Thank you very much, now I finally found, where the size of Composites is computed!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried hinting the desided size via `GridData`?

```
final GridData data = new GridData();
data.widthHint = 1000;
data.heightHint = 1000;
canvas.setLayoutData(data);
```